# Show that the canonical modal for the modal logic K4.3 has no branching to the right

Tags: logic, modal-logic

K4.3 is the normal logic axiomatized by 4 ($\Diamond \Diamond p \to \Diamond p$) and
$$
\Diamond p\land\Diamond q \to\Diamond(p\land\Diamond q)\lor\Diamond(p\land q)\lor\Diamond(q\land\Diamond p)\
$$
or by 4 and
$$
\Box(p\land\Box p \to q) \lor \Box(q\land\Box q \to p)\
$$

(These two forms of .3-axioms are given seperately and it remains to show they are equal. So it might be better to use only one of them in a proof.)

I have shown that the canonical modal for the modal logic S4.3 (given by $S4 + \Box(\Box p \to q) \lor \Box(\Box q \to p)$) has no branching to the right (the proof is similar to the one in  [Show that the canonical modal for the modal logic s4.3 has no branching to the right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542553/show-that-the-canonical-modal-for-the-modal-logic-s4-3-has-no-branching-to-the-r)).

However I find it difficult to deal with the precondition $u \neq v$ , where w, u and v are points in the canonical model for K4.3 such that
$$
Rwu, Rwv, \lnot Ruv, \lnot Rvu, u \neq v.
$$
Since $\lnot Ruv$, there is $\varphi$ such that $ M,u \models \Box \varphi$ but $M,v \not \models \varphi$. Since $\lnot Rvu$, there is  $\psi$ such that $ M,v \models \Box \psi$ but $M,u \not \models \psi$. And since $u \neq v$, there is $\chi$ such that $\chi\in u$ but $\lnot\chi \in v$.

It seems that I should consider three formulas $\varphi$, $\psi$ and $\chi$ rather than two. I've tried to use them to construct other two fprmulas, but found it difficult.

This question is in Blackburn, Patrick, Maarten de Rijke, and Yde Venema, 2001, *Modal Logic*, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, p.211, Exercise 4.3.3.

Thank you so much! ^_^

Comment: I've added that formula in my question. I'm sorry for my carelessness. Thank you a lot! ^ω^ @Shaun

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of @blueberry_pie is correct. And I do the proof using $\Box (p\wedge \Box p\to q)\vee \Box (q\wedge \Box q\to p)\notin w$ as (.3').

Define $\mathbf{K4.3'}=\mathbf{K4}+(.3')$. Let $(W^{\mathbf{K4.3'}},R^{\mathbf{K4.3'}},V^{\mathbf{K4.3'}})$ be the canonical model for $\mathbf{K4.3'}$. Assume $R^{\mathbf{K4.3'}}ww',R^{\mathbf{K4.3'}}ww''$, and $w'\neq w''$, not $R^{\mathbf{K4.3'}}w'w''$, not $R^{\mathbf{K4.3'}}w''w'$. We want to get a contradiction. As not $R^{\mathbf{K4.3'}}w'w''$, there exists $\psi $ such that $\Box \psi \in w'$ and $\psi \notin w''$(then $\neg \psi \in w''$). Similaely, there exists $\phi $ such that $\Box \phi \in w''$ and $\phi \notin w'$(then $\neg \phi \in w'$). As $w'\neq w''$, there exists $\chi $ such that $\chi \in w'$ and $\chi \notin w''$. Then $\neg \chi \in w''$. Note $\Box \gamma \vdash_{\mathbf{K}}\Box (\gamma \vee \pi )$. We have $((\chi \vee \psi )\wedge \Box (\chi \vee \psi )\to (\neg \chi \vee \phi ))\notin w'$, and $((\neg \chi \vee \phi )\wedge \Box (\neg \chi \vee \phi )\to (\chi \vee \psi ))\notin w''$. Then $\Diamond \neg ((\chi \vee \psi )\wedge \Box (\chi \vee \psi )\to (\neg \chi \vee \phi ))\wedge \Diamond \neg ((\neg \chi \vee \phi )\wedge \Box (\neg \chi \vee \phi )\to (\chi \vee \psi ))\in w$. Let $\alpha =(\chi \vee \psi ), \beta =(\neg \chi \vee \phi )$. Then $\Box (\alpha \wedge \Box \alpha \to \beta )\vee \Box (\beta \wedge \Box \beta \to \alpha )\notin w$. Contradictory!

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The proof works similarly as in the case of K4.3: Since $M, u \models \square \phi \wedge \neg\psi$, it follows that $M, w \models \Diamond(\square\phi \wedge \neg \psi)$. Analogously, we have $M,w \models \Diamond(\square\psi \wedge \neg \phi)$. So $w$ satisfies the consequent of the instance of the .3-axiom, which results from the substitution that maps $p$ to $(\square \phi \wedge \neg \psi)$ and $q$ to $\square \psi \wedge \neg \phi$.

If

- $M, w \models \Diamond((\square \phi \wedge \neg \psi) \wedge \Diamond(\square \psi \wedge \neg \phi))$,

there are points $x, y$ with $x\models \square \phi, x Ry, y \models \neg \phi$. Contradiction.

If

- $M, w \models \Diamond ((\square \phi \wedge \neg \psi) \wedge (\square \psi \wedge \neg \phi))$,

there is a point $x$ with $wRx, x \models \neg(\phi \wedge \square \phi \rightarrow \psi ) \wedge \neg( \psi \wedge \square\psi \rightarrow \psi)$. But this contradicts the fact that $w$ satisfies

- $\square(p \wedge \square p \rightarrow q) \lor \square(q \wedge \square q \rightarrow p)$.

If

- $M, w \models \Diamond(\Diamond(\square \phi \wedge \neg \psi) \wedge (\square \psi \wedge \neg \phi)$,

there are points $x,y$ with $x \models \square \psi, xRy, y \models \neg \psi$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Sorry but I still wonder how we can get "there is a point x with wRx,x⊨¬(ϕ∧□ϕ→ψ)∧¬(ψ∧□ψ→ψ)" from "M,w⊨◊((□ϕ∧¬ψ)∧(□ψ∧¬ϕ))".  So would you mind giving more details? Besides, those two forms of .3-axioms are given seperately in the exercise, so I worry if I can directly use both of them in a proof (it remains to show those two of them are equal; sorry I should have made it clear, and I'll edit my question). In fact it seems I've done using ◊p∧◊q→◊(p∧◊q)∨◊(p∧q)∨◊(q∧◊p) now (I'll write down my answer below), but I don't know how to use the other one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I've done withe the .3-axiom of the form
$$
\Diamond p\land\Diamond q \to\Diamond(p\land\Diamond q)\lor\Diamond(p\land q)\lor\Diamond(q\land\Diamond p)\
$$.
But I don't know how to use the other one yet.

Proof:

Assume not. Then there are w, u and v in the canonical model such that
$$Rwu, Rwv, \lnot Ruv, \lnot Rvu, u \neq v.$$

Since $\lnot Ruv$, there is $\varphi$ such that $M,u \models \Box \varphi$ but $M,v \models \Box \varphi$. Since $\lnot Rvu$, there is $\psi$ such that $M,v \models \Box \psi$ but $M,v \models \Box \psi$. And since $u \neq v$ , there is $\chi$ such that $\chi \in u$ but $\lnot \chi \in v$.

Then $M,u \models \Box \varphi \land \lnot \psi \land \chi$, and $M,v \models \Box \psi \land \lnot \varphi \land \lnot \chi$.

And since $Rwu$ and $Rwv$, $M,w \models \Diamond (\Box \varphi \land \lnot \psi \land \chi) \land \Diamond (\Box \psi \land \lnot \varphi \land \lnot \chi)$

So $w$ satisfies the consequent of the instance of the .3-axiom, which results from the substitution that maps $p$ to $(\Box \varphi \land \lnot \psi \land \chi)$ and $q$ to $(\Box \psi \land \lnot \varphi \land \lnot \chi)$.

If

- $M,w \models \Diamond (\Diamond (\Box \varphi \land \lnot \psi \land \chi) \land (\Box \psi \land \lnot \varphi \land \lnot \chi)),$

then there are $x$, $y$ such that $M,x \models \Box \psi$ and $Rxy$ and $M,y \models \lnot \psi$. Contradiction.

If

- $M,w \models \Diamond ((\Box \varphi \land \lnot \psi \land \chi) \land \Diamond 
   (\Box \psi \land \lnot \varphi \land \lnot \chi)),$

we can see a contradiction analogously.

And if

- $M,w \models \Diamond ((\Box \varphi \land \lnot \psi \land \chi) \land 
   (\Box \psi \land \lnot \varphi \land \lnot \chi)),$

there is $z$ such that $M,z \models \chi$ and $M,z \models \lnot \chi$. Contradiction.

So our assumption is false.

Comment: I wonder if I should construct other formulas substituting p and q, in order to use the other form of .3-axiom. And this proof is enlightened by the one given by @sequitur. Thank you again for your help! ^ω^